# How to join two observables?

Tags: javascript, json, rxjs

I have two json observables I need to join as they originally come separated from another source so this is just an example as I'm trying to understand rxJS too.

```
var obs = Rx.Observable.from([
  { id: "1", url: "whatever.jpg"},
  { id: "2", url: "whatever2.jpg"},
  { id: "3", url: "whatever3.jpg"}
])

var list = Rx.Observable.from([
  { first: "Gary", last: "Simon", age: "34"},
  { first: "Jane", last: "Simon", age: "34"},
  { first: "Juan", last: "Simon", age: "34"}
])

// I tried this   
var newObs = Rx.Observable.merge(list,obs)
// and this
var newObs = Rx.Observable.forkJoin(list,obs)
```

The point is I need a new json that looks roughly like this:

```
[{
    "first": "Gary",
    "last": "Simon",
    "age": "34"
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "url": "whatever.jpg"
}]
```

How should I do that with RxJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`zip`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-zip):

```
Observable.zip(obs, list).subscribe(([obsItem, listItem]) => console.log(obsItem, listItem));
```

Notes:

- The widely used convention is to add `$` as a suffix to the observable names. e.g. `obs$`, `list$`
- If the length of input observables is not the same. The result will take the length of the shortest one. e.g. `obs` has 3 items, `list` has 5 items, then the result observable will only emits 3 items and skip the last 2 items of `list`.

Comment: it joins the elements but how do I access each value? I see the json but I wanna see each value I can't access it "x => console.log(x.id) == undefined"

Comment: Try `x => console.log(x[1].id)` or `([x, y]) => console.log(y.id)`